# GestureDetector is active when there is decoration in Container Widget

Tags: containers, gesturedetector, decoration

**I wrapped expanded container in a row with gesture detector. I wanted gesture detector to use all the available space when user press the container. But when I use container without decoration, gesture detector detects only the child of the container, not its constraints. When I add decoration with borders Gesture detector works as I expect. **

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
return SizedBox(
  height: 120,
  child: Card(
      color: Colors.white24,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
      semanticContainer: true,
      elevation: 5,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 5),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  var weatherData =
                      //await WeatherModel().getCityWeather(widget.apiary.apiaryLocation);
                      await WeatherModel().getLocationWeather(
                          apiary.latitude!, apiary.longitude!);
                  if (weatherData == null) {}

                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return ApiaryHomePage(
                      locationWeather: weatherData,
                      apiary: apiary,
                    );
                  }));
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '${(index + 1)}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        title,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () =>
                          EditApiaryPage.show(context, apiary: apiary),
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.edit,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        size: 32,
                      )),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        AlertDialogs().showAlertDialog(context, () {
                          final database = ref
                              .read<FirestoreDatabase?>(databaseProvider);
                          database!.deleteApiary(apiary.apiaryId);
                        }, AppLocalizations.of(context)!.deleteApiary);
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.delete,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: 32,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
);
```